# How to check if handler has callback

Tags: android

In my Application I have created a dialog on a button click and started handler on dialog creation now I want to remove handler's callbacks after dialog dismissed and on activity so I have created a handler on oncreate method of activity  which continously checks for flag that I set true when dialog dismisses and when flag become true handler's callback should be removed but handler's callbacks are not removed.

```
final Handler handler_Alerts = new Handler();
    Runnable r_Alerts = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       if(Flag){
            handler1.removeCallbacks(rhandler1);
           }
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In Handler", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    handler_Alerts.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                  }
        };

    handler_Alerts.postDelayed(r_Alerts, 1000);
```

Comment: You want to remove a callback if it doesn't have a callback? How can you remove something that doesn't exist?

Comment: """Now I want to remove this handler's callback if it
doesn't have any callbacks."""

how. do you want to remove something that does not exist?

Comment: Sorry for that sentence but is there any method like handler.hasmessage() for callback so that I can check before removing callback that handler has callback and I have to remove that callback

Comment: please read this it might be useful to you
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816262/check-if-android-handler-has-callbacks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to check if it has a particular runnable (***edit*** although since API 29, you can now use `handler_Alerts.hasCallbacks(r_Alerts)`).

For your application, you can call

```
handler_Alerts.removeCallbacks(r_Alerts);
```

to remove any instance of r_Alerts inside the Handler queue, or

```
handler_Alerts.removeCallbacks(null);
```

to remove all the runnable in its queue

Answer (score 5):

Do not have the reputation to comment, but Blackbelt's:

```
handler_Alerts.removeCallbacks(null);
```

should not work according to developer website, since the passed Runnable cannot be null.
Instead call:

```
handler_Alerts.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

to remove all callbacks and messages.

Answer (score 2):

is that possible to check has the postDelayed() was called or not?

```
One quick fix, in method assign some boolean variable to true and then just perform checking.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you could send an empty message when you first put a callback in and then check for that message in the handler. This empty message could represent that there is a callback present. Removing that message later could then be used similarly to see if the callback is still there. Don't have a relevant situation such as this to go from, but thought that I would at least try and share a possibility.

```
...
Map.handler.sendEmptyMessage(CALLBACK_PRESENT_INTEGER);
...
if(Map.handler.hasMessages(CALLBACK_PRESENT_INTEGER)
...
Map.handler.removeMessage(CALLBACK_PRESENT_INTEGER);
```

...
This is probably not ideal, but could be a potential solution if you have access to your handler from the point where your callback is used. Not sure if there is a direct way to find out.

[for detail...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816262/check-if-android-handler-has-callbacks)

Comment: This looks like an unattributed verbatim copy of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15816840/3063884

Answer (score 0):

Ok another solution could be just to extend existing Handler class (Kotlin):

```
class MarkingHandler: Handler() {

    private val markedCallbacks = ConcurrentHashMap<Int, Runnable>()

    fun postMarkedDelayed(markId: Int, delayMIllis: Long, callback: () -> Unit) {
        if(hasMarkedCallback(markId))
            throw IllegalArgumentException("The markId id is already exist in the handler")
        markedCallbacks[markId] = Runnable {
            markedCallbacks.remove(markId)
            callback()
        }
        postDelayed(markedCallbacks[markId], delayMIllis)
    }

    fun removeMarkedCallback(markId: Int) {
        if(hasMarkedCallback(markId)) {
            removeCallbacks(markedCallbacks[markId])
            markedCallbacks.remove(markId)
        }
    }

    fun hasMarkedCallback(markId: Int) = markedCallbacks.contains(markId)
    fun hasMarkedCallbacks() = markedCallbacks.size > 0
}
```

Usage:

```
        val handler_Alerts = MarkingHandler() 
        handler_Alerts.postMarkedDelayed(1, 1000) runnable@{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In Handler", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            handler_Alerts.postMarkedDelayed(1, 1000, return@runnable)
        }

        if(handler_Alerts.hasMarkedCallback(1) /*|| handler_Alerts.hasMarkedCallbacks()*/) {
            handler_Alerts.removeMarkedCallback(1)
        }
```

The similar approach can be use to wrap `post(delayMIllis: Long)` method as well in the `MarkingHandler` class